# Not updating using jsp using netbeans glassfish 4.1.1 server

Tags: jsp, database-connection

My sample code that doesn't update my database:

```html
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
String success = ""; 
String regId = request.getParameter("regId");
String nostc = request.getParameter("nostc");
String address_nostc = request.getParameter("address_nostc");

try{
Connection conn = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/final_project","root", "");



String sqlEDIT1 = ("UPDATE initial_reg SET "
        + "nostc=?"
        + "address_nostc=?"
        + " WHERE regId=?");
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlEDIT1);

ps.setString(1,nostc);
ps.setString(2,nostc);
ps.setString(3,regId);

    int i = ps.executeUpdate();
    if(i>0)
    {
        success = "Form submitted";
        
    }
    else
    {
        success = "There was an error.";
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
%>
<%= success %>
```

When I tried to update only one field which is the nostc, it will update my db. But when edited the file and tried to add this code: 
    String address_nostc = request.getParamater("address_nostc");
and inserted this code(after nostc):
     + "address_nostc=?"

it will not update my db. I posted my code above. thanks.

Comment: Try this query `"UPDATE initial_reg SET nostc=? , address_nostc=? WHERE regId=?"` you forgot to insert `,` after nostc.

Comment: yap.. + "nostc=?"
        + ",address_nostc=?"
        + " WHERE regId=?");

Comment: Second, change `ps.setString(2,nostc);` to `ps.setString(2,address_nostc);`

Comment: @JajtonJuntilla please update your question if there were typos that are not existing in your actual code. Also, please check if there's any exception caught and let us know which one it is (if that doesn't solve the problem already)